# Why is the fetch percentage inside the RemoteConfig parameter so small?

Tags: firebase, fetch, firebase-remote-config, ab-testing, firebase-ab-testing

I perform 2 A/A tests for each of the two applications (ios/android), using a random toggle for 100% of the application users with a 50/50 distribution there.

However, on Android in RemoteConfig, the values for the variant do not exceed 40-45%, and on iOS-5-7%. At the same time, more than 5-7% of the total number of events were collected. Tell me please, what do these percentages mean in a particular example?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's most likely you are seeing cached values from the clients as by default, Remote Config will cache values for about 12 hours before trying to download new values from the service.

Seeing this kind of split may take a day or more to see the results propagate which is also
based on your user's usage, which is compared to the total baseline.

It is recommended to read about this loading behavior [**HERE**](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/01/firebase-remote-config-loading.html).